# Django question: need help using HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django, parameters, view, httpresponse

I have a  view called save_service_request. At the end of the code it redirects to a view called send_confirmation_email.

```
def save_service_request(request):
try:
    # some stuff
except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(service_order, args = [contact.client.pk , service_type]))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(send_confirmation_email, args = [order.pk, service_type]))
```

Now I want do something with this. If I am at the page

```
(r'^quote/service_order/(?P<client_id>\d+)/(?P<request_type>\d+)/$', views.service_order),
```

go to send_confirmation_email view using HttpResponseRedirect.

But if the url before was called.

```
(r'^quote/service_order/edit_items/(?P<client_id>\d+)/(?P<request_type>\d+)/$', views.service_order2),
```

go send it to this

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(delete_confirmation, args = [order.pk, service_type]))
```

This maybe possible using if statements.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you are doing. What does that mean: `If the url was`, what url?

Comment: @Skirmantas if I am in views.service_order, the next view I want to go to is a view called send_confirmation_email. If I am in views.service_order2 I want to go to the view delete_confirmation

Comment: Still I can't understand your problem. In `service_oreder` make a redirect to one location, in `service_order2` make redirect to other location.

Comment: @Skirmantas `service_order` and `service_order_2` share the same template. It has a form where if the form is submitted, the page will be redirected to `send_confirmation_email`. I do not want `service_order2` to go there. Only service_order. Instead send `service_order2` to `views.delete_confirmation`.

Comment: Do not comment on your question.  Please **update** your question with the additional facts.  After you **update** your question, please delete these very hard to read comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `next` attribute:

In `views.service_order`

```
context = {'next': reverse('views.send_confirmation_email')}
```

In template:

```
<form action='?next={{ next }}'>
```

In view which validates form:

```
if 'next' in request.GET:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET['next'])
```